# how to find all the exsiting file systems in UNIX?

Tags: mount

I want to mount a device to a designated dir, how can I know what file systems already exist in my machine? I am using a NFS system, Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **df** command with `-a` argument:

```
df -a
```